# Checking two numpy arrays element wise equivalent or not with floating point values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to check two numpy arrays are equivalent or not.

Code:
import numpy as np

```
def numpy_equal():
    x = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0.000000000000001000000000000000000000002])
    y = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0.000000000000001000000000000000000000001])

    #assert np.all(x == y)
    #assert np.array_equal(x, y)
    assert np.allclose(x ,y)
    #assert np.isclose(x, y)

numpy_equal()
```

I tried all these but it's saying both arrays are equal. After decimal, if I have long digits (e.g., like  0.00000000000000000000000000000000100000002) and want to compare those values, how to get it using numpy arrays?

Can I increase the tolerance level?

Comment: The NumPy arrays are irrelevant here. Try simply `0.000000000000001000000000000000000000002 == 0.000000000000001000000000000000000000001` and you'll get `True`. Python and NumPy floats are stored to a fixed precision (usually 53 bits).

Comment: So, is not there any way to prove 0.000000000000001000000000000000000000002 == 0.000000000000001000000000000000000000001  as false ?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. If you really need high precision arithmetic, you can try to implement your own class that can handle the precision, mantisse, exponent, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `decimal` module of python for such long floats:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import numpy as np

def numpy_equal():
    x = np.array([2, 3, 1, Decimal("0.000000000000001000000000000000000000001")])
    y = np.array([2, 3, 1, Decimal("0.000000000000001000000000000000000000002")])
    assert np.all(x == y) # raises
    assert np.array_equal(x, y)

numpy_equal()
```